# attr library classes are sharing default value?

Tags: python, attr

Here is an example of strange attr behavior.

```
import attr

@attr.s
class List:
  l = attr.ib(default=[])

a = List()
b = List()

a.l.append(1)

print(b.l)
# output is [1], this is unintuitive, why not []
```

Why is this happening, and how can I get the behavior that we obtain a new list each time?

Comment: The list `default=[]` is shared between the `List` instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below code will create a 'private' list for each instance of `List`
See [here](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/api.html?highlight=factory#attr.Factory) for the docs.

```
import attr

@attr.s
class List:
  l = attr.ib(factory=list)
```

Answer (score -1):

Though I don't know much about `attr` package. But I am pretty sure `l` is a static variable for the class `List`, which means it is not a member variable and it is shared across all the instances of `List`. You may want to make it become a member variable.

Comment: This is incorrect. Because of how attrs works (see the decorator being applied), `l` is not "static" (by which I guess you meant a class variable, or `ClassVar`. The issue here was that the default value was mutable (which attrs specifically warns against), and the solution is using `l = attr.ib(factory=list)` as per the accepted answer.